# React-native project Build failed: Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have some issues trying to generate a new release of my apk.
(However the app runs normally in debug with `react-native run-android`)

First of all i had this Output message:

> Task :react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac Note: Some input
>   files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for
>   details.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> **>  What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-  maps:lintClassPath'.**
>
> > Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0.   Searched in the following locations:
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.jar
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.jar
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.jar
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.jar
> >           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom
> >           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.jar
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/Desktop/Ulabs/appreactnative/testApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom
> >           file:/C:/Users/kev_w/Desktop/Ulabs/appreactnative/testApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.jar
> >     Required by:
> >           project :react-native-maps*

1.What i did to fix this:
Adding `google()` in my **android/build.gradle** >> `allprojects {...}` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After adding this, the build is successfull, but my apk crashes instantly when i open it...

As i said in the beginning, before adding `google()`, my project was running normally in debug with `react-native run-android`.
But now, neither the apk nor the debug project works.

It crashes without any log.

Then i've tried to run apk build removing `google()` and adding `lintOptions` in my android/app/build.gradle:

```
android {
 (...)
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

in my `android/app/build.gradle`, to avoid the lint-gradle error > IT DID NOT WORK.

Here is my whole `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    /*implementation project('react-native-maps')*/
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I've spent hours trying to find out a solution on the net, but nothing worked for me. Either i've my `run-android` working and app not crashing but could not build any apk, or I can build it but it crashes immediately when i run it (apk or run-android)...

If anyone could save my mental health please ^^...

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried with google() before jcenter() ? It worked for me:

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here;
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me when I added `google()` to `allprojects` before `jcenter()`.  However, when I tried to put `google()` first in `buildscript` I got an error.  It compiles, so I'm just going to be satisfied with not 100% understanding what is going on here.

Comment: The order was not important for me, probably it's related to a dependency build inside your project.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the exact same issue and found two way to solve it.

First one: downgrade gradle to version 2.2.3

Better one: for me the problem was created by react-native-map, to solve it you have to edit the app/build.gradle from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

to:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+"
```

Comment: Specifying dependency versions using "+" is not recommended because your build may not be reproducible in the future.

Comment: Indeed, this is a problem. But i tried many versions and only the "+" is working. Is there a way to know wich version is the good one? (Without trying all of them)

Answer (score -1):

The following code worked for me.

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
  projects/modules.

 buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please show what this answer adds to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49858034/4126843)

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written